# $A.createComponents() with lightning:buttonMenu and lightning:menuItem

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Having some problems dynamically creating a [lightning:buttonMenu](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_buttonMenu.htm) using [$A.createComponents()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm).  Creating the buttonMenu works fine but as soon as I try to add a [lightning:menuItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_menuItem.htm) I get the following when I click the menu:

error:

```
Uncaught Assertion Failed!: Descriptor for Config required for registration : undefined  throws at ...
```

helper method from component:

```
createFilterMenu: function(cmp) {
    var options = cmp.get('v.filterOptions')
    var menuOptions = [
        [
            'lightning:buttonMenu', {
                'aura:id': 'filterMenu',
                'iconName': 'utility:filterList',
                'alternativeText': 'Filter Selection',
                'value': cmp.getReference('v.filter'),
                'onselect': cmp.getReference('c.filterChange')
            }
        ],
        [
            'lightning:menuItem',{
                'label': 'test',
                'value': 'test'
            }
        ]
    ]
    $A.createComponents(
        menuOptions,
        function(components, status, errorMessage) {
            if (status === 'SUCCESS') {
                var menuDiv = cmp.find('menu')
                var menu = components[0]
                var item = components[1]
                menu.set('v.body',item)
                menuDiv.set('v.body', menu)
            } else if (status === 'INCOMPLETE') {
                console.log('No response from server or client is offline.')
            } else if (status === 'ERROR') {
                console.log('Error: ' + errorMessage)
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you help narrow it down? Whats in menu.set("v.body", item); ? can you remove as much as you can while still getting the error?

Comment: This is a nested component example as mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm).  menu.set('v.body',item) is setting the body for the lightning:buttonMenu with a lightning:menuItem.  The hope is to be able to dynamically build that menu this way.

Comment: Can I get the full stack trace? Can you break on the error and get more information? I tried to reproduce using your createComponents call, but it didn't happen.

Comment: @Kris Gray Did you ever figure out what this was? Running into it myself.

Comment: @WarbleSync I'm getting this same error in the exact same circumstances. I dynamically create a buttonMenu with child menuItems, and when I click on the buttonMenu the error is thrown. If I skip adding the children, clicking on the buttonMenu produces an empty dropdown and no error. Definitely related to the children somehow. Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I didn’t get a full stack trace. :) send it to me I’ll track down the culprit. I know the reason already but not the offender.

Comment: Please let me know if anyone find the way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to http://dfyjkt.blogspot.com/2018/09/is-it-impossible-to-dynamically.html

The reason is buttonMenu's body is Aura.ComponentDefRef, not the usual Aura.Component.
The workaround in that post does not work for me, but it explains why it does not work.